# how can i call setState from difference class

Tags: flutter, class, dart, set, zip

**FLUTER DART**

I have two files like this

one is stful class like this

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      onPressed: () {
        updateField() // here i call function from other page
      },
      child: null,

    );
  }
}
```

and one is function into other file or page like this

```
  updateField()async{
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(currentUser.uid).update({
      "faceType" : currentUser.faceType ,
    });
  setState(() {
      currentUser.faceType= faceType;
    });
  }
```

but once i use setstate it says setstate is not defined , how can i use it please
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're calling setState within the stateful widget.

The setState is a method available within only Stateful widgets.
Anyone outside the stateful widget is just a custom method you wrote.

That being said you can use a state management library of your choice and you'll be able to easily change different states within your stateful widget.

The best part is that the logic code would not have to be within the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a function in the Statefull widget that handles SetState Cases.
and within this function you call whatever functions in other files of your project.
So, in your case you can have a function in the Statfull widget as follows:

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
_updateScreen() async {
   try{
     await updateField();
     setState(() {
       // handle the new state with Provider or whatever you prefer 
     });
   }catch(error){
     // handle errors
   }
}
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      onPressed: () {
        _updateScreen() 
      },
      child: null,

    );
  }
}
```

and the other file could has the function as follows:

```
updateField()async{
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(currentUser.uid).update({
      "faceType" : currentUser.faceType ,
    });
  
  }
```